# Jenkins parameterized build - POST data to url instead of including in query params?

Tags: jenkins

The standard Jenkins notify url is:

```
JENKINS_URL/job/demo/build?token=TOKEN_NAME or /buildWithParameters?token=TOKEN_NAME
```

I sent a longer uri (with a long query param) and I got:

```
<h1>Bad Message 414</h1><pre>reason: URI Too Long</pre>response ended: 414
```

is there a way to POST to the Jenkins url with a body, and use the body with a *parameterized build*?

Or perhaps include it as an HTTP Header? (That is, if headers are allowed to be longer than URIs).

Comment: Do you send your query with a curl command ?

Comment: I send it with Node.js, but if you can get a `curl -X POST` command to work, that is fine as a proof of concept

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example with curl command :

```
curl -X POST JENKINS_URL/job/JOB_NAME/build \
  --user USER:TOKEN \
  --data-urlencode json='{"parameter": [{"name":"id", "value":"123"}, {"name":"verbosity", "value":"high"}]}'
```

If you want more information, from official sources :

- https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API
- https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/218889337-How-to-build-a-job-using-the-REST-API-and-cURL-

Comment: so can you confirm that the request body fields go into the parameterized build params?

Comment: Yes, in my example above, the parameterized build is launched with two params : "id" (set to "123") and "verbosity" (set to "high").

Comment: Don't forget to include the CSRF token if applicable (it probably is).  From the aforementioned [Remote Access API docs](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API#RemoteaccessAPI-CSRFProtection):  _If your Jenkins uses the "Prevent Cross Site Request Forgery exploits" security option... **you have to send a CSRF protection token as an HTTP request header** ...you can obtain the header needed in the request from the URL JENKINS_URL/crumbIssuer/api/xml (or .../json). \[Which will return\] something like "Jenkins-Crumb:1234abcd", which you should add to the subsequent request._